# AES Encryption between two languages not producing output

Tags: perl, encryption, aes, pbkdf2

Trying to send data though AES encryption from Javascript to Perl.  However, I am not getting any output when decoding on the Perl side.

EDIT:

1. Desired behavior - To have the Perl code unencrypt messages encrypted by the listed Javascript.
2. Specific problem or error - Perl code does not decrypt javascript messages due to unknown reasons.
3. Shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem - Detailed as follows:

**JAVASCRIPT ENCRYPT**

```
var keySize = 256;
var ivSize = 128;
var iterations = 100;

function testcrypt(){
  var pass = 'testpass';
  var msg = 'testmsg';
  var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
  var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(pass, salt, {
      keySize: keySize/32,
      iterations: iterations
    });
  var iv = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
  var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(msg), key, {
    iv: iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
  });
  
  // salt, iv will be hex 32 in length 
  // append them to the ciphertext for use  in decryption
  var packet = salt.toString()+'-'+ iv.toString()+'-' + encrypted.toString();
  alert(packet);
}
```

OUTPUT IS -> 71b851532027b022c50f1a389254fca4-d8a9d7c4fa30f7d9427a5762e2c5794b-8S/JOXgDYuRloLKBiH5fYg==

**PERL DECRYPT**

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Crypt::CBC;
use Crypt::PBKDF2;
use MIME::Base64;
print "\nGot: ".decrypt('ebdfcbd226b7dbc73e77a29d31fab723-3daf178979cb03087f5258907e73e547-CyG6R0EU9s0c8dBCAZk6Jg==', 'testpass');
print "\nGot: ".decrypt('71b851532027b022c50f1a389254fca4-d8a9d7c4fa30f7d9427a5762e2c5794b-8S/JOXgDYuRloLKBiH5fYg==', 'testpass');

sub decrypt{
        my $encrypted = shift;
        my $key = shift;

        my($salt,$iv,$packet)=split '-',$encrypted,3;
        $packet = decode_base64($packet);
        my %options=(
                key_len => length $key,
                iv_len  => length $iv,
                iterations => 100,
               # hash_class => 'HMACSHA2',
                hash_class => 'HMACSHA1',  # To match CryptoJS
        );
        $options{output_len}  =  $options{key_len} + $options{iv_len};

        my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(%options);

        my $AES = Crypt::CBC->new(
                #-key    => $pbkdf2->PBKDF2($key,$salt),# Was Reversed
                -key    => $pbkdf2->PBKDF2($salt,$key),
                -cipher => 'Cipher::AES',
                -pbkdf  => 'pbkdf2',
                -header => 'none',
        );

       return $AES->decrypt($packet);

}
```

Comment: IV handling is incorrect. In encryption you are adding it to the ciphertext, in decryption you are deriving it using PBKDF2.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this was closed. It seems possible to answer the question. On  the other hand, if you're trying to decrypt by looking for a code sample instead of by mimicking the encryption routine, then I guess this is the outcome.

Comment: Also, both codes use different digests (HMAC/SHA1 in JS, HMAC/SHA256 in Perl), in Perl in [`PBKDF2()`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::PBKDF2#PBKDF2-($salt,-$password)) the arguments are swapped, salt and IV are hex encoded in the CryptoJS code, the Perl code lacks decoding (as far as I can see).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes - Can you be more specific on the IV handling?  I see it being added by "AES.encrypt" in the javascript. Is this not the case?  Yes, we are trying to learn from coding examples.  Mimicking the encryption routine is how we got the $key/$salt reversed.  Would be better to have a proper coding sample instead.  I'm hoping this will be that example!

Comment: The hex decoding of salt and IV is still missing. For decryption, the *implicit* key derivation must be disabled and the IV must be passed (the latter fixes the wrong IV handling). For the *explicit* key derivation the output length has to be set to 32 bytes.

Comment: In the first code sample you use the random IV directly in the `encrypt` routine. In the decrypt the corresponding `$iv` is however only used to derive the IV length. The problem with following code samples is that you basically program by debugging, and that's pretty hard when it comes to cryptography, as everything gets randomized. Furthermore, it doesn't allow you to really grasp the algorithms used (such as the SHA-256 based HMAC that Topaco told you about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the issues have already been addressed in the comments. In the meantime, some changes have been made to the code. The following bug list refers to the originally posted code:

1. The CryptoJS code hex encodes salt and IV, the Perl code lacks hex decoding.
2. The CryptoJS code uses HMAC/SHA1, the Perl code HMAC/SHA256
3. In the Perl code, the arguments are swapped when calling `PBKDF2()`.
4. In the CryptoJS code, the key is derived from the password via PBKDF2. In the Perl code, the key derivation is done twice (explicitly with `PBKDF2()`, implicitly with `-pbkdf => 'pbkdf2'`).
5. In the CryptoJS code, the IV is randomly generated. In the Perl code the IV is derived together with the key via PBKDF2.

These bugs can be fixed as follows:

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Crypt::CBC;
use Crypt::PBKDF2;
use MIME::Base64;

print "\nGot: ".decrypt('ebdfcbd226b7dbc73e77a29d31fab723-3daf178979cb03087f5258907e73e547-CyG6R0EU9s0c8dBCAZk6Jg==', 'testpass');
print "\nGot: ".decrypt('71b851532027b022c50f1a389254fca4-d8a9d7c4fa30f7d9427a5762e2c5794b-8S/JOXgDYuRloLKBiH5fYg==', 'testpass');

sub decrypt{
    my $encrypted = shift;
    my $pwd = shift;

    # get IV, salt and ciphertext
    my($salt,$iv,$packet)=split '-',$encrypted,3;
    $iv = pack("H*", $iv);                      # Fix regarding 1.
    $salt = pack("H*", $salt);                  # Fix regarding 1. 
    $packet = decode_base64($packet);
    
    # derive key
    my %options=(
            output_len => 32,           
            iterations => 100,
            hash_class => 'HMACSHA1',           # Fix regarding 2.
    );
    my $pbkdf2 = Crypt::PBKDF2->new(%options);
    my $key = $pbkdf2->PBKDF2($salt, $pwd);     # Fix regarding 3.
 
    # decrypt
    my $AES = Crypt::CBC->new(
             -pbkdf  => 'none',                 # Fix regarding 4.
             -key    => $key,   
             -iv     => $iv,                    # Fix regarding 5.
    );

    return $AES->decrypt($packet);
}
```

When the script is executed, the ciphertexts are now decrypted correctly (versions used: Crypt::CBC: 3.04, Crypt::PBKDF2: 0.161520).

---

The internal key derivation cannot be applied because the salt used is 16 bytes long and the internal key derivation supports only 8 byte salts (error message for other salt lengths: *argument to -salt must be exactly 8 bytes long...*).
In case of an 8 bytes salt the internal key derivation can be used as follows:

```perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use Crypt::CBC;
use Crypt::PBKDF2;
use MIME::Base64;

print "\nGot: ".decrypt('0dad5e7e0c105e82-665304727191506bd818cd48ac9917a0-DXF+Bh/K4ESEw1tgtp6p2Q==', 'testpass');

sub decrypt{
    my $encrypted = shift;
    my $pwd = shift;

    # get IV, salt and ciphertext
    my($salt,$iv,$packet)=split '-',$encrypted,3;
    $iv = pack("H*", $iv);                      
    $salt = pack("H*", $salt);                  
    $packet = decode_base64($packet);

    # derive key and decrypt
    my $AES = Crypt::CBC->new(
             -pbkdf   => 'pbkdf2',                 
             -key     => $pwd,   
             -salt    => $salt,
             -hasher  => 'HMACSHA1',
             -iter    => 100,
             -header  => 'none',
             -iv      => $iv,                    
    );

    return $AES->decrypt($packet);
}
```